# Retry NSXMLParser if error occurred

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

In my project NSXMLParser get xml-data from specific web-site. 
Usually it works fine.
But sometimes it have to take several attempts to get data.
In that case there's error in "parseErrorOccurred" (when xml-data not loaded).

How to retry xml-parsing for several times to be sure that data loaded successfully (for example 5 times)?

Comment: Don't parse the data until you successfully obtain the data.

Comment: I guess that it will stop parsing. And how can I repeat it again if error still exist?